# SQL to compact index after deletion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't for the life of me remember what the SQL (SQL Server 2005+) is to compact indexes after deletion i.e.

```
PK Identity  col1 col2
1            abc  def
3            abc  def
```

id 2 has been deleted - whats the command to essentially compact the indexes while keeping referential integrity (there's a one line statement)

Thanks, (and I know I'm going to 'face-palm' when I see the answer)

Comment: SQL Server typically reuses disk space freed up by deletion automatically - when it's needed. It's typically not a good idea (nor is it really needed) to "compact" your database or index files - just let it be - SQL Server will reuse the space

Comment: are you worried about disk space or just a cleaner index?

Comment: I'm not really worried about disk space - I just want a way to compact the identity index say after many millions of deletions (a long time from now) so that we use less of the available values of int. From the link down below and my memory (which is flawed obviously at best) I believe the ALTER INDEX REBUILD is the one liner I was after -as promised... "FACE-PALM"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term in SQL is [Reorganizing and Rebuilding Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx) and the commands for each of these are:

```
ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE
```

and

```
ALTER INDEX REBUILD
```

But as per the opening line on that link "The SQL Server 2005 Database Engine automatically maintains indexes whenever insert, update, or delete operations are made to the underlying data." so just leave it to the server.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are really keen on minimizing disk space do not do it but perhaps you are using express and are approaching the size limit?

Anyway, this way you can compact your database:

```
  DBCC SHRINKFILE 
  (
  { file_name | file_id } 
  { [ , EMPTYFILE ] 
  | [ [ , target_size ] [ , { NOTRUNCATE | TRUNCATEONLY } ] ]
   }
)
[ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]
```

Comment: This won't compact the indexes.

Comment: Like I said, it seems (look also at the comment of Marc) that OP is looking for disk-space, not for a new index. this will help with the diskspace problem as I clearly wrote so downvoting is a bit premature before he answers my comment to the original question

Comment: @Pleun I think the down vote was a bit harsh but the question was as clearly aimed as I could at re-organizing index with no mention of disk-space. Thanks for the input though :)

Comment: no problem, i was a little bit misguided by the inital comment of marc_s :)